# a concrete example of metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm learning functional analysis by myself these days (using an old textbook "foundations of modern analysis" by Avner Friedman). The beginning of this field is metric space: to generalize theorems regarding completeness, compactness, continuity from Euclidean space to metric space.

These are quite abstract. So I was wondering when you think of a metric space, what is a concrete example in your mind? (for your understanding of theorems and properties on a metric space, like completeness, compactness, continuous functions etc.?) Of course Euclidean space is a metric space, but I'm afraid this example is too trivial or too special here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A lot of the intuition you get from Euclidean space is useful in proving statements in general metric spaces. For instance, people will often draw open balls as open disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'd argue that this is a good example to keep in your mind, but you are right that you have to be careful and not assume every metric space will behave like Euclidean space.

Comment: An example which looks quite different from Euclidean space is $L^p$ space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces. The metric is $d(f,g)=\|f-g\|_p$.

Comment: Hunestly? I just think of a sheet of paper and a yardstick to measure distances. Compactness is the hardest part. But in that case, every open set has a size so any finite area covered by patches will be covered by some finite number patches if we apply the patches one by one and pick one near the edge of the last pne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important examples of metric spaces other than the Euclidean spaces are spaces of functions, for example the space of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ or the space of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ or stuff like that.